# System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program

Tags: serialization, clr, zeroformatter

All,

I am using ZeroFormatter for serialization of a big object, sometimes it is giving following error while serializing the error, this issue is observed after using Union concept of ZeroFormatter for inheritence.

Here are the exception details:

> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
>   at ZeroFormatter.DynamicObjectSegments.ZeroFormatter_Formatters_DefaultResolver.Colibrium.Common.Ontology.Rating.Factors.RateFactor$Formatter.Serialize(Byte[]& , Int32 , RateFactor )
>   at ZeroFormatter.Formatters.CollectionFormatter`3.Serialize(Byte[]& bytes, Int32 offset, TCollection value)
>
>   at ZeroFormatter.DynamicObjectSegments.ZeroFormatter_Formatters_DefaultResolver.Colibrium.Common.Ontology.Rating.RateClass$Formatter.Serialize(Byte[]& , Int32 , RateClass )
>
>   at ZeroFormatter.Formatters.CollectionFormatter`3.Serialize(Byte[]& bytes, Int32 offset, TCollection value)
>   at ZeroFormatter.DynamicObjectSegments.ZeroFormatter_Formatters_DefaultResolver.Colibrium.Common.Ontology.Rating.PackagePlan$Formatter.Serialize(Byte[]& , Int32 , PackagePlan )
>   at ZeroFormatter.Formatters.CollectionFormatter`3.Serialize(Byte[]& bytes, Int32 offset, TCollection value)
>
>   at ZeroFormatter.DynamicObjectSegments.ZeroFormatter_Formatters_DefaultResolver.Colibrium.Common.Ontology.Rating.Package$Formatter.Serialize(Byte[]& , Int32 , Package )
>
>   at ZeroFormatter.Formatters.CollectionFormatter`3.Serialize(Byte[]& bytes, Int32 offset, TCollection value)
>   at ZeroFormatter.DynamicObjectSegments.ZeroFormatter_Formatters_DefaultResolver.Colibrium.Common.Ontology.Rating.PackageGroup$Formatter.Serialize(Byte[]& , Int32 , PackageGroup )
>   at ZeroFormatter.Formatters.CollectionFormatter`3.Serialize(Byte[]& bytes, Int32 offset, TCollection value)
>
>   at ZeroFormatter.DynamicObjectSegments.ZeroFormatter_Formatters_DefaultResolver.Colibrium.Common.Ontology.Rating.Group.GroupRatingResults$Formatter.Serialize(Byte[]& , Int32 , GroupRatingResults )
>
>   at ZeroFormatter.ZeroFormatterSerializer.CustomSerializer`1.Serialize[T](T obj)
>   at Colibrium.Utility.Library.ObjectConverter`1.ConvertO
>   bjectToBinaryZeroFormatter(T p_object)
>
> in C:\TFS\UPMC\Repos\Colibrium.Utility.Library\ObjectConverter.cs:line 407

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for [DynamicFormatter](https://github.com/neuecc/ZeroFormatter/blob/853a0d0c6b7de66b8447b426ab47b90336deca2c/src/ZeroFormatter/Formatters/DynamicFormatter.cs#L212-L980) it appears the library tries to optimize formatting of your user types by generating CLR types at runtime to serialize / deserialize the user type to a byte array. Based on the error, it seems there must be a bug in this IL generation.

You should report this problem in the [ZeroFormatter project issues](https://github.com/neuecc/ZeroFormatter/issues) but note you will likely need to have a good way to reproduce this issue, as tracking down an `InvalidProgramException` is very challenging.

Answer (score 0):

In case you happen to have Application Insights in use, the exception may be thrown due to [issue 18323 reported to .Net Core CRL](http://%20https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/18323)

The issue is reported on .Net core, but I have also reported it on .Net Framework due to the solution seeming to work also there.

> ApplicationInsights has moved towards a Preinstalled Site Extension model and does not have the offending bits anymore. In addition, the private Site Extension will not be updated as it is estimated to be deprecated within a month. You should be able to upgrade to the preinstalled site extension through the ApplicationInsights configuration in the AppService blade in Azure.
>
> However, if you want an immediate solution for the private site extension, you can workaround the issue by removing the following two files in the site extension and restarting the site:
>
> - Instrumentation32\ProductionBreakpoints_x86.config
> - Instrumentation64\ProductionBreakpoints_x64.config
>
> This will effectively remove the part of AppInsights extension causing issues.